# Why Does IQueryable Select Has Invalid Arguments With DTO but works with object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a particular LINQ query that is doing a group by an anonymous type and then selecting into an object via projection.  The query works fine when selecting in to the object.  I am now trying to change the usage of the query to go in to a DTO that contains all the properties being projected to the object, however when I switch the types from the Object to the DTO, the query starts giving me an error that the IQueryable.Select has invalid arguments.

```
IQueryable<type> result = from o in blah where some_conditions
                          orderby o.Name
                          group o by new {o.Value1, o.Value2, o.Value3} into groupedO
                          select new type 
                          {
                               Value1=groupedO.Key.value1,
                               Value2=groupedO.Key.value2,
                               Value3=groupedO.Key.value3
                          }
```

Works fine when "type" is my original object but fails when I make it my DTO that has properties Value1,Value2 and Value3 (of the appropriate types).

I realize this probably isn't enough information to find the problem, but I'd also accept any pointers as to a direction to look for what could cause the issue.  I can't tell what could possibly be different.  Also, if I remove the group, the query works fine, so it is something specific to the anonymous type in the group.

The exact error is

> `System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,someDalClass>>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' has some invalid arguments.`

Comment: Well it would help if you'd give the *precise* error message. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: A error message would help... A wild guess: properties on DTO don't have setters or have different type(s).

Comment: Updated with exact error.  Sorry, I mentioned that the error specified that the IQueryable was saying that the select had invalid arguments, but if you want the exact wording, it is now posted in the question.

Comment: @Eugene DTO works fine if I drop the groupby from the selection and instead assign static values to the properties.

Comment: @AJHenderson: `select` returns an `IEnumerable`, doesn't it? Also, for the grouping, you have to access the members using the `Key` property, e.g. `groupedO.Key.Value1`. I realize it's just an example, but I'm trying to simulate your scenario, and can't seem to reproduce that error.

Comment: @Voithos - Yeah, I doubt very much that the situation is easily reproducible.  It appears to be something very specific to my particular object and DTO, but I have no idea what it could be since they appear to be identical.  The .key thing was just an error in my annonymising.  I believe Select will still return a queryable, just when it is enumerated, it will run through the query and apply the selection.  It works fine as an IQueryable return when "type" is my business object that contains one of the DAL objects o.

Comment: You have anonymized it too much.. If you can recreate the issue with a small piece of program, it would demystify it. what is the structure of 'type' and your DTO.. include any interface they inherit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facepalm moment.  The issue was that the DTO had a typo in a field name and wasn't compiling, however it was lost in the error log.  Fixing the typo in the DTO made the types match properly and all is now well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use GroupBy the result is IGroupable. So you should use something like this:

```
IQueryable<type> result = from o in blah where some_conditions
                          orderby o.Name
                          group o by new {o.Value1, o.Value2, o.Value3} into groupedO
                          select new type 
                          {
                               Value1=groupedO.Key.value1,
                               Value2=groupedO.Key.value2,
                               Value3=groupedO.Key.value3
                          }
```

because your values o.Value1, o.Value2, o.Value3 is in Key of IGroupable.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that answer.  As it turns out that was just a mistake I made in annonymising the code.  The actual code is using .Key.  I updated my example code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the messiness, but just as a proof-of-concept, the following compiles and runs in LINQPad. So, it doesn't to be a problem with using an anonymous type, nor with grouping.

```
public class MyBlah
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value1;
    public int Value2;
    public int Value3;
}

public class MyDTO
{
    public int Value1;
    public int Value2;
    public int Value3;
}

void Main()
{
    MyBlah o1 = new MyBlah
    {
        Name = "asdf",
        Value1 = 2,
        Value2 = 3,
        Value3 = 4
    };

    MyBlah o2 = new MyBlah
    {
        Name = "fdsa",
        Value1 = 3,
        Value2 = 4,
        Value3 = 5
    };

    MyBlah o3 = new MyBlah
    {
        Name = "HI",
        Value1 = 3,
        Value2 = 4,
        Value3 = 5
    };

    List<MyBlah> lst = new List<MyBlah>();
    lst.Add(o1);
    lst.Add(o2);
    lst.Add(o3);

    IEnumerable<MyBlah> result = from o in lst
                                 orderby o.Name
                                 group o by new {o.Value1, o.Value2, o.Value3} into groupedO
                                 select new MyBlah
                                 {
                                     Value1 = groupedO.Key.Value1,
                                     Value2 = groupedO.Key.Value2,
                                     Value3 = groupedO.Key.Value3
                                 };

    IEnumerable<MyDTO> resultDTO = from o in lst
                                   orderby o.Name
                                   group o by new {o.Value1, o.Value2, o.Value3} into groupedO
                                   select new MyDTO
                                   {
                                       Value1 = groupedO.Key.Value1,
                                       Value2 = groupedO.Key.Value2,
                                       Value3 = groupedO.Key.Value3
                                   };
}
```